# MySql - sorting on large table performance issue

Tags: php, mysql

I have large table over 10M rows, InnoDB.

When I use **ORDER BY** in query it takes 15 seconds (without ORDER BY 0.008s).

```
SELECT product_id, name, manufacturer_id FROM items 
WHERE manufacturer_id = 704 ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 0, 48
```

I have simple index on: product_id, name, manufacturer_id
I have multiple-column index on: manufacturer_id and name

So I dont't use any JOIN or other slowing technique. Just one condition, sorting by one column.

Do you have any tip how speed up my query?
I read about "partitioning in Mysql" is this good when I have over 1,000 manufactures and I need search by each manufacturer but somethimes I need work with table as "one piece"?

**Query with EXPLAIN:**
*id:     1

select_type:   SIMPLE

table:   items

type:   index

possible_keys:  manufacturer_id
 
key:  name

key_len:    767

ref:    NULL

rows:   15168

Extra:   Using where*

**show create table:**
Table: items
Create Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
 `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `product_no` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `url` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `price` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `manufacturer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`),
 KEY `name` (`name`),
 KEY `name_2` (`name`,`manufacturer_id`),
 KEY `manufacturer_id` (`manufacturer_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=27100137 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

UPDATE:
I tried change innodb_buffer_pool_size from 5MB to 2G and it seems it helps.

When I check status in console with SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST, State of running query is stuck in: Sending data, this state taking all time

Comment: The multicolumn index on `(manufacturer_id, name)` is the correct one. (You could add the `product_id`, but I guess it is the primary key anyway) . Make sure you really have it (and in that column order!) and that it is used. Also make sure the `name` is completely included in it (no prefix index, no blob/text-type). To check for it, write `explain` infront of your query (`explain select product_id, ...`) and that it is in the key column and/or post the output here along with your table definition.

Comment: How many records does that query return? Is it common? Stick a redis cache in front maybe.

Comment: If you have a multicolumn index on `(manufacturer_id, name)`, you don't need the simple index on `manufacturer_id`.

Comment: @mkaatman it return 48 because I use LIMIT without it (for manufacturer_id = 704) 26,634
For testing I'm using SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE

Comment: @Barmar simple indexes are for other queries

Comment: It doesn't matter. A multicolumn index also acts as an index for any prefixes of the column list. So the multicolumn index can also be used when you just need an index on the first column. The simple index is redundant.

Comment: @Solarflare I added EXPLAIN result

Comment: MySQL is taking the wrong index (on name), so there seems to be something wrong. Could you add the table description (the output of `show create table items`)? It looks like you are hitting one of the key size limits (767) with your index on name, which could indicate that you might have used a prefix in your multi column index for the `name` part to get it to create (but which makes it useless for ordering, which in turn would explain the behaviour).

Comment: It seems that because column name is VARCHAR I have to use FULLTEXT not just simple index. I'm doing some test...

Comment: A fulltext index is not useful here (you cannot use it to order your result, just to find something, and you are not searching for a name here). Please add the output of `show create table items` so we can see your actual indexes and the datatype of your columns. It's hard to find out what might go wrong here without all the information. You probably tried something you thought was correct (e.g. using a fulltext index, or, probably, a prefix index), and it might not work as you think it does; but to see what you did exactly and not keep guessing we need to see the actual table definition.